# Sky Broadband Shield

Tags: firewalls

I was just wondering about the implications of Sky's new revelation of a so-called 'shield'. Is this actually even a security feature or just an advertisement stunt for Captain America? I can find very little information on this (maybe I am looking in the wrong place) but it seems this is just a URL filter that all ISP's employ anyway.

Is Sky just giving users a false sense of security or is this actually a next-gen security product of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be the name they're using for their content filtering system. I think they provide [enough information to establish that](http://help.sky.com/security/stay-safe-online/sky-broadband-shield-explained), once you understand that ISPs are trying to get out ahead of legal regulation.

The main indicator to me is the fact that it's on by default, which is exactly what Cameron demanded. If you know what Sky broadband had before (I don't) then you could make a more detailed comparison of what has changed vs. what's in the proposed legislation.

Yes, ultimately it's a URL, domain and IP address filter, but it's broader in scope than the ones ISPs have previously used.

The people who've voted for the Online Safety Bill in its readings to date, probably think it's a next-gen security product. I have some doubts personally.

Comment: I See. I think they wrapped it up in a pretty bow which led me to question it. I guess in combination with AV it might add a little more security. Just feels like the advert portrays something of an impenetrable 'shield' which will no doubt leave some users misinformed.

Comment: @Sighbah: right, each ISP has given their version of it a name for marketing purposes. Which makes sense if you're going to have to tell customers that it's a new thing they're getting but can ask to opt out of. Who knows, maybe some of them will actually be inspired to make their marketing name actually mean something by putting work into making it do something useful that on-your-PC or on-firewall filters don't do ;-) Until then it's squarely a same-gen security product, deployed one hop further away from the user.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Putting up a filter without user's consent would not go down to well. Let's hope they do get inspired it would at least leave the bad guys scrambling for other attack vectors no doubt. It just seems we go through infinite firewalls and filters to get to google.com these days haha. From PC -> Router -> ISP -> GreatfirewallofUK :D. Thanks for your comments though they were informative.